# Using python's os.walk to search for a specific dir name?

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, tree, os.walk

I have a question in regards to walking through a directory tree and returning all the directories that contain the word "test". My problem is when I run with this code,

```
for root,dirnames,filenames in os.walk("Path/to/my/files"):
    for dirname in fnmatch.filter(dirnames, "test"):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.ext"):
            file.write(os.path.join(root,filename)+ "\n")
```

I get every directory that contains "test". So some directories might be named "systest" or "testplan" or "tester". I dont want those directories. I know I should use a regex or something like that but I just can't seem to wrap my mind around it. Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

I have figured another way to do it with regex but its a bit wonky because of the file seperator in windows

```
testPattern = re.compile(".*\\\\test\\\.*\.java")
for root,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(rootPath):
    for file in filenames:
        path = root+"\\"+file
        m = testPattern.match(path)
```

Thanks!

Comment: "returning all the directories that contain the word "test"." and later "I get every directory that contains "test"." Where is the problem?

Comment: I think OP wants directories that match `r'^test$'`, not ones that match `r'test'`

Comment: "match `r'^test$'` is probably more simply written as `== 'test'`, especially for an OP who can't wrap his mind around regexes. But I don't think that's what he means, I think he means something like `'test' in dirname.split()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a guess here, but I think by saying you want directories that 'contain the word "test"' but don't want directories 'named "systest" or "testplan"', you're looking to split the name into words, and see if one of those words is `"test"`.

That's easy:

```
for dirname in dirnames:
    if "test" in dirname.split():
        # ...
```

---

But I don't think your logic makes sense anyway. For example, let's say you have this structure:

```
foo/
|---a test/
|   |--- stuff1.ext
|---another test/
|   |--- stuff2.ext
|---thing1.ext
|---thing2.ext
```

On the first `walk` step, you're going to go through all the subdirectories in `foo`, and, for each one with the word `test` in their name, you're going to go through all the files in `foo`. So, you're going to write out `thing1` and `thing2` twice, and never write out `stuff1` or `stuff2`.

I'm guessing what you're *actually* trying to do is this:

```
for root,dirnames,filenames in os.walk("Path/to/my/files"):
    if "test" in os.basename(root).split():
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.ext"):
            file.write(os.path.join(root,filename)+ "\n")
```

Comment: Do you need to use root.split(os.sep)?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz: `root.split(os.sep)` isn't much better than `root.split('\\')`. The whole point of `os.path` is to let you treat paths as paths, instead of as strings. Use `os.path.split`—or, in this case, `os.basename`. But thanks for pointing out that I wasn't doing _any_ of the above.